# How to increase RAM by swapping memory from Internal Phone Storage..?

Tags: insufficient-memory, ram, swap

I have `Micromax Canvas Music A88`. I just want to allocate memory from internal phone storage to RAM.

**Memory Detail :**

RAM: 512 MB

Internal Memory: 2 GB

I want to transfer 500 Mb from internal storage to RAM...

Can anyone help me how to transfer...??

**Note: I don't want to swap from micro sd card**

Comment: You cannot increase RAM! Only you can swap ROM for application usage..answer given below is for ROM

Comment: I wouldn't do that ,swap memory on android phones is pointless you will make your phone slower and decrease the life time of your internal storage ,I will post a better answer when I log in from my PC ,on the other hand zram is a good alternative for android with low ram but it needs to be compiled in the kernel and the best compression algorithm to use with it is LZ4 ,like I said I will post a more detailed unswer later this is just to comment and give you some key words to Google

Comment: Community bump prevention: this question was closed because the question seems to have been abandoned (OP hasn't visited the site after posting the question, and no answers have score above 0). If anyone can evaluate the existing answers, feel free to vote accordingly and reopen the question (or mod-flag the question requesting for reopening). For anyone else having the same issue, please post a new question and refer to this question as additional context.

Comment: @AndrewT. The OP seems confused about the difference between RAM and flash memory. The software linked in the answer is about compressing the contents of flash, but the answer seems to think it can be used to create a swap partition. That's pretty pointless on Android device flash memory. Leave the question closed, or delete it.

Answer (score -1):

**You will need Root access for this!**

(First You Need To Take Backup from CMW/TWRP)

- Download [MT657x Data Repartition Tool3.0A](http://wwww.mediafire.com/?69208004dmnwix8)
- Install app and choose the size you want to swap (e.g 1GB) from internal sdcard.
- Select OK.
- Reboot to recovery.
- Wipe cache/dalvik cache.
- Factory reset.
- Restore Backup.
- Reboot .
- **DONE**