# Is it possible to convert internal storage to RAM without Root?

Tags: applications

There is this apk called SWAP no Root. The developer claims that this app can convert the internal storage up to 5GB to RAM without root. I read this [discussion](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/77279/314204) that I need root to be able to do that. Is that even possible? Or is it just hoax? Since it's an apk, I'm assuming it doesn't involve PC to proceed. I'm not familiar with swap, though.

Comment: 1. Using swap is not equivalent to "convert the internal storage to RAM" // 2. Using a file as swap without root is nothing more than a joke. // 3. Even with root, using internal storage for swap isn't a good idea. Go for ZRAM if possible. More explanation [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/220042/218526).

Comment: I am sure that the storage memory will not be as fast as the main memory. So, even if you can do this, the device will become more unusable than now. Its better to remove some apps or configure some of them to be inactive, when not in use.

Answer (score 0):

"In reality, there is at least one app that I know of that allows you to create zram and swap basically without limits or whatever your device allows you to do, called Ultra Ram Swapper. Although it requires root permissions, you can find an old patched version without the need for superuser on several YouTube channels

Comment: The OP said without root.